# Anyone want to expand on what "можения" means?

Tags: лексикон

It is said in a Vladimir Vysotsky song.
Прочь влияния извне,
привыкайте к новизне,
вдох глубокий до изне–
можения.

I believe it comes from the word мочь but I'm not completely sure. I'd be grateful if anyone wanted to explain the meaning.

Comment: I presume you know the meaning of "изне"? ;)

Answer (score 11):

The reason why the word was divided with a dash is that the rhyme demands it.

> Прочь влияния извне,
>
> Привыкайте к новизне,
>
> Вдох глубокий до изне-
>
> можения!

[And Vysotsky actually stressed that pause there.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jkojGf_u2uI) It is typical of him.

Whereas normally the lyrics are

> Прочь влияния извне,
>
> Привыкайте к новизне,
>
> Вдох глубокий до изнеможения.

Actually, there was such a phenomenon in the USSR as [morning exercises](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e6lDdBt5kwY). Recommendations were read by a radio (and later - TV) announcer, it was accompanied by piano music, and the aim was to help Soviet citizens get healthier by speading sports habits among the population.

This, together with the specifics of the TV of that time, evoked a number of [jokes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BtQH4ZzcT4Y), and Vysotsky wrote his song as a mockery.

Answer (score 5):

The phrase is "до изнеможения" - "until exhaustion".
изнеможение - exhaustion

It does come from мочь. "До изнеможения" literally means "until you can't anymore".

Answer (score 1):

Изнеможение. 
Root is "мочь", cf. я могу- I can, он может - he can.
Не - is negation. 
Из - means 'out', 
Hence, изнеможение - exhaustion, your strengh is out, and you can not do anything, you are weak (usually physically). 
Technically, *изнеможение* is from verbs *изнемогать, изнемочь*. Just to be exact.

Answer (score -2):

It means “Abilities” and really comes from the word Мочь